# Compose Google Storage Objects without headers via CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I was wondering if it would be possible to compose Google Storage Objects (specifically `csv` files) without headers (i.e. without the row with column names) while using `gsutil`.

Currently, I can do the following:

```
gsutil compose gs://bucket/test_file_1.csv gs://bucket/test_file_2.csv gs://bucket/test-composition-files.csv
```

However, I will be unable to ingest `test-composition-files.csv` into Google BigQuery because `compose` blindly appended the files (including the column names).

One possible solution would be to download the file locally and process it with `pandas`, but this is not ideal for large files.

Is there any way to do this via the CLI? I could not find anything in the docs.

Comment: How are those `CSV` files generated? And, do you need the column names at all?

Comment: They are generated using another CLI tool that parses OpenStreetMap data. There doesn't seem to be any option from that library (`osmium-tool`). And I will need the column names for the first one, but all other appending `csv` files need their names dropped. One option would be to append them blindly and then process the resulting file afterwards I suppose, but again not ideal.

Comment: How are you ingesting the `CSV` into BQ? and is this something that you are going to do systematically or from time to time?

Comment: Systematically. This is all being run in a Dataflow job. I was trying to just stream the csv files using a `WriteToBigQuery` operator but I was running into performance issues so I am now just using `bq load` jobs, but since I have so many files I am composing them to reduce the amount of API calls.

Comment: The Cloud Storage Compose command knows nothing about the format of the object's data. This is a file concatenation operation to improve performance and large file uploads. The compose command is not for combining files with structure, such as CSV, that requires processing to combine.

Answer (score 1):

By reading the comment, I think you are spending effort in the wrong way. I understood that you wanted to load your files into big query, but the large number of file prevented you to do this (too many API calls). And dataflow is too slow.

Maybe you can think differently. I have 2 solutions to propose

- If you need "near real time" ingestion, and if file size is bellow 1.5Gb, the best way is to build a function which read the file and perform a stream write to BigQuery. This function is triggered by a Cloud Storage event. If there is several file in the same time, several functions will be spawn. Be careful, stream write to [BigQuery is not free](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#streaming_pricing)
- If you can wait up to 2 minutes when a file arrive, I recommend you to build a Cloud Functions, triggered every 2 minutes. This function read the file name in a bucket, move them to a sub directory and perform a load job of all the files in the sub directory. You are limited to [1000 load jobs per day (and per table)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs), a day contains 1440 minutes. Batch every 2 minutes you are OK. The load job are free.

Is it acceptable alternatives?